# White Area in Display Using XIB still shows white space despite Safe Area Guide Being Set

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, xib

Okay so I have a XIB File that I used to show a view that has an image and a couple buttons. I initially had an issue that made the picture to stretched out which I was able to fix by setting the safe area layout constraints to all sides and setting the constant to 0.

However now that I have done that there is a white space above my content view and I am not sure how to make it disappear.

I have attached the screenshots of what my current constraints look like . Maybe someone sees something that I do not.

[image: Image View Constraints]

[image: View Constraints]

[image: Current Screen]

See the white bar at the top

Comment: Can you add the view stack screen shot?

Comment: @K.R.SaravanaKumar how do you see that

Comment: On the Left side of the storyboard, There is a list of ViewControllers and its childviews

Comment: @K.R.SaravanaKumar its already there

Answer (score 0):

From Your ViewController-> Attribute Inspector just check 'Under Opaque Bars' . Like following picture. please share your view stack if its not work . 
[image]

Comment: this is a xib file where do I find that option

Comment: In your ViewController where this xib presented